# Can't get Spinner's value in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I have a spinner and in `strings.xml` i have some items for this spinner, my problem is that i cannot get the value and the error is the following:

I tried every possible solution that i found all over the internet without luck.
I am using samsung Note 4 with android 6.0.1

```
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Here is my code:

```
public class activity_mainnew extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

long choose_whale_sound;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainnew);

//SPINNER
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.richard_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.whale_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        choose_whale_sound = id;
        Toast.makeText(activity_mainnew.this, "ID: " + choose_whale_sound, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }


}
```

Comment: R.array.whale_array where this is defined , can you post that code

Comment: is it solved???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter constructor is defined like this:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

For details you can follow this link [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Try by changing this statement

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.whale_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.whale_array);
```